# Display notes log with emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Here is the use case that I want to have in org-mode

I have next org-mode structure

```
Work.org file
* heading one
    - Note taken on [2018-12-20 Fri 16:07] \\
      Some note here
    - Note taken on [2018-12-21 Fri 12:37] \\
      Some note here

Personal.org file
* headin two
    - Note taken on [2018-12-21 Fri 16:07] \\
      some note here
    - Note taken on [2018-12-22 Fri 12:37] \\
      some note here
```

I want to see the log statistics for 2018-12-21 and as result have

```
    * heading one
        - Note taken on [2018-12-21 Fri 12:37] \\
          Some note here

    * headin two
        - Note taken on [2018-12-21 Fri 16:07] \\
          some note here
```

Any idea how I can implement it or use some existing features?
PS: Look like I can't use agenda features as the heading items doesn't have TODO

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to see your desired result via the agenda and some special commands in it:

when you press "v" while in Agenda you can see which additional commands are possible:

- "[" will include the inactive timestamps
- "E" will include the first few lines of your entry (the number of lines can be configred via: "org-agenda-entry-text-maxlines").

It is not exactly what you want, but quite close.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question was asked quite some time ago so perhaps this is newer functionality, using org-version 9.1.14...  I would have added this as a comment to @sanenr9 answer, but I do not have that wizard level yet <:-(

Note, this does not work in tag-type agenda buffers, so not what I'm looking for.

From Agenda day or week view use `v` and select `L` - "Log-all" which does then display all entries with updates and their logs within the selected date range.